# Splitting list of sums into a sum of lists

Tags: list-manipulation, vector

I want to split a list of sums into a sum of lists For example, I'd like to turn

```
{{x + y + z}, {x}, {y}, {z}}
```

into

```
x{{1}, {1}, {0}, {0}} +y{{1}, {0}, {1}, {0}} + z{{1}, {0}, {0}, {1}}
```

as you would when turning a vector with a sum inside it into a sum of vectors.

I've looked all over for documentation for this kind of thing, but I couldn't find anything :(. It would be even further helpful if someone could tell me how to put these three vectors into a single list, I know I can append them, I'm just not sure how to do it when they're being multiplied by something.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using `CoefficientArrays`:

```
expr   = {{x + y + z}, {x}, {y}, {z}};
coeffs = Last@CoefficientArrays[expr, {x, y, z}] ~Flatten~ 1 // Transpose // Normal
(* {{1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}} *)
```

You can just `Dot` this with the variable list to get back the original list:

```
{x, y, z} . Map[List, coeffs, {2}]
(* {{x + y + z}, {x}, {y}, {z}} *)
```

Comment: You are a saint, thank you so much!